# He had 4 sons. What is the meaning of this sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

He had 4 sons. Does this deliberately mean that the sons are dead now?

Comment: Not without additional context.

Comment: @J.R. I was looking at the sentence - Mr.Smith had 4 daughters, each daughter had a brother... How many children does Mr.Smith have? The answer was: It's zero... The whole paragraph is in past tense. That brings to a conclusion that Mr Smith has 0 children at present..

Comment: Why would you leave that out of your question? Questions are far more interesting (and easier to answer) when such [details](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) are provided in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It doesn't mean they are dead. It just means that their births were in the past.

On the other hand "He has four sons" does imply that he and his sons are alive, and is probably more common in describing a person.

You would normally see the past tense form in an impersonal context, such as a biography. For example, it could be used in a factual description of a person who has died

> John Lennon had two sons, who both became musicians.

or when discussing the time when a person became a parent

> Mick Jagger has 8 children. He had his first daughter in 1970. He had his most recent child in 2016, aged 73.

It could also mean that the children are dead.

> Mohammed had four sons that were killed in a car accident.

Comment: Surely all births are in the past, regardless of whether the parents are said to **have** children or **had** them.

Comment: @RonaldSole Correct, which is why "had" in this context doesn't imply anything further about them. Similar to a phrase like "he *fathered* 4 sons".

Comment: But It *can* mean that they are dead. Simply saying that it doesn't is wrong. If all four of his sons died from misadventure, you would *still* say *he had four sons*. Context is key. The identical sentence can mean different things. Everything being equal, it's less *likely* it means they are dead—but it's certainly not impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Per James K's answer, this does not imply that the any of the sons are dead. It's unusual to use the past tense as noted in that answer, but it's more likely implying that the subject (the father) is dead than any of the sons.